# Stream using VLC and fifo file

Tags: streaming-video, vlc, cvlc

I have a Rapberry Pi (model B), wired connected on network.

**I want to stream using raspistill and save loop jpeg picture into a fifo file.
In the other side I want to read this fifo file with VLC, and display it.**

I tried somthing like this:

```
mkfifo fifo
wget -O /home/pi/fifo http://192.168.1.27:8554 & omxplayer -r /home/pi/fifo
```

and this:

```
cvlc --rc-host 192.168.1.27:8554 /home/pi/fifo -d
```

to read localy the stream (networkless) I tryed:

```
cvlc < fifo
```

*(rpi and PC are both on linux)*

*(I already stream without fifo on VLC player)*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)s are not for saving or reading more than once. You may find [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) better suited to your goals.

Untested guess at what you want(split a network stream):

```
mkfifo myfifo1 myfifo2 && curl -s http://192.168.1.27:8554 | tee myfifo1 > myfifo2;
```

Other guess at what you want(display and save on rpi):

```
raspistill --fullpreview --output - >> jpgs.dat
```

or using more than one file in a loop

```
raspistill --fullpreview --output $(date +%Y%M%dT%H%m%S).jpg
```

or using raspivid

```
raspivid -fps 2 --timeout 0 --fullscreen --output $(date +%Y%M%dT%H%m%S).h264
```

Note that you can set the fps on raspivid and with it's temporal compression it may be better than looping raspistill in some conditions.

Comment: Following this command, nothing happend. without the -s argument it say "could not connect to the host". I'll learn more about the "tee". I don't know what's "curl".

Comment: @Lyreco curl is similar to wget (they are for the most part interchangeable) If it could not connect to your server than your server was not serving. wget should throw a similar error under the same conditions.

Comment: I'm not connected to the Internet, so I want to use only VLC, raspistill & fifo.

Comment: @Lyreco Please clarify your question; if you don't want to use more than one computer there is no need for wget/curl, regardless you have to use tee to split the stream or ask cvlc to save it. also note that you can just use raspistill --fullpreview --output - >> myfile.